# Why isn't Orderless an Attribute of And?

Tags: language-design, built-in-symbols, attributes, logic

In standard logic `And` is a commutative operator. Still, in *Mathematica*, `And` doesn't have the `Orderless` attribute:

```
Attributes[And]
(* {Flat,HoldAll,OneIdentity,Protected} *)
```

This may have not been the case in the past. On page 190 of David Wagner's book "Power Programming with Mathematica" one finds a table with functions having different attributes. In that table `And` is listed as one of the functions that have the `Orderless` attribute. At the time of publication *Mathematica* version 3.0 had just released.

There are good reasons for `And` not to have `Orderless` among its attributes. One of them is efficiency. Since the argument order remains fixed, the programmer can sort the arguments so that the expected execution time will be minimized.

Another reason for eschewing `Orderless` is that, in `Operator[x,y]`, the evaluation of `x` can have such side effects on `y`, and perhaps this may cause `Operator[x,y]` and `Operator[y,x]` have different values (I am not sure about this). However, this second argument for not including `Orderless` in the list of attributes of `And` also applies to functions like `Max`, `Times`, and `Plus`, and still all of these functions have the `Orderless` attribute.

One can see the consequences of these choices:

```
(x + y) == (y + x)
(* True *)
(x && y) == (y && x)
(* (x && y) == (y && x) *)
```

So was `Orderless` avoided in `And` just for efficiency reasons or is there any other specific feature of `And` that requires not including `Orderless` among its attributes?

Comment: You already answered your own question.  `And` is not `Orderless` so it can be short circuiting.  This is not only about efficiency.  You can also do stuff like `FooQ[x] && FunnyFooQ[x]` where `FunnyFooQ` won't even run without errors for something that is not a "Foo".  Short circuiting makes it possible to write more concise and therefore clearer code without too many `If`s.

Comment: To preserve [short circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you mentioned, `And` is not `Orderless` just for efficiency; its arguments are evaluated one by one to prevent unnecessary computation. `Orderless` attribute would require sorting, which require more computation...

In `a && b && c`:

1. `a` is evaluated. If it is `False`, the evaluation ends, and the output is `False`. If not, the evaluation proceeds.
2. `b` is evaluated. If it is `False`, the evaluation ends, and the output is `False`. If not, the evaluation proceeds.
3. `c` is evaluated. If it is `False`, the output is `False`. If it is `True`, then the output is `True`.

This is very efficient.

Plus, as @Szabolcs mentions, not having `Orderless` attribute allows you to use short-circuit evaluation (a.k.a. McCarthy evaluation).

> "You can safely use `a && b` even when `b` wouldn't correctly run unless `a` has evaluated to `True`. E.g. `StringQ[s] && StringStartsQ[s, "x"]`"

---

e.g. checking for perfect square using mod 256 (only 44 values occur for perfect squares mod 256 - [more info](https://gmplib.org/manual/Perfect-Square-Algorithm.html)):

```
mods = AssociationMap[True &, Array[Mod[#^2, 256] &, 256]];
perfectsquareq1 = 
  Lookup[mods, Mod[#, 256], False] && IntegerQ[Sqrt[#]] &;
perfectsquareq2 = 
  And @@ {Lookup[mods, Mod[#, 256], False], IntegerQ[Sqrt[#]]} &;
```

The first function uses `And`. The second function forces the evaluation and then uses `And`.

See the difference in speed:

```
Array[perfectsquareq1, 100000]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.254216, Null}`

```
Array[perfectsquareq2, 100000]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.926911, Null}`

Comment: This property is called short circuiting and it's not only about efficiency.  You can safely use `a && b` even when `b` wouldn't correctly run unless `a` has evaluated to `True`.  E.g. `StringQ[s] && StringStartsQ[s, "x"]`

Comment: @Szabolcs Hm, forgot about that. Thanks for telling me.